# Enable - Disable ports history in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, send-port, receive-location

I am using BizTalk 2010.

I would like to search the history of a receive location or Send Port, to see when they were enabled and when disabled. I have access to BizTalk database to run queries. If also I could see for which reason they were disabled it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is - as of yet - no auditing support within BizTalk Server itself unfortunately. Up to BizTalk Server 2013 R2

There are however several monitoring tools built on top of BizTalk Server which will give you a similar experience. However, be aware that these will not be able to detect and/or state a reason why a port/location was started/unenlisted/stopped when this happens straight into the BizTalk Admin Console, instead of the tool.

I don't want to state a preference of some tool, but one of the tools I know, which is capable of this, is BizTalk360 - http://www.biztalk360.com/
This is quite a well known tool within the community. However, it is a licensed tool.

I do not know about any open source/free tools which are capable of the same things.

*FYI: I don't have any affiliation with them whatsoever. If there are more tools capable of doing so, please let me know in the comments, and I will add them here as well.*

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was hoping to get what I want by querying directly the BT database, but I think this is not so easy.

Comment: @user3417479 I don't think BizTalk even logs that information into the database at all.  The best you can get is the current status and the date last modified e.g.  nPortStatus & DateModified from [BizTalkMgmtDb].[dbo].[bts_sendport]

Comment: @Dijkgraaf thanks. This helped me a lot. I cannot have the history of the status but at least it is easy to find which port or receive location is disabled.